# What is the correct way to unset a linux environment variable in python?

Tags: python, environment-variables

From the documentation:

> If the platform supports the `unsetenv()` function, you can delete items in this mapping to unset environment variables. `unsetenv()` will be called automatically when an item is deleted from os.environ, and when one of the `pop()` or `clear()` methods is called.

However I want something that will work regardless of the availability of `unsetenv()`. How do I delete items from the mapping if it's not available? `os.environ['MYVAR'] = None`?

Comment: `unsetenv` works on "most flavors of Unix, Windows" according to the docs.

Comment: hmmm, I wasn't sure. I'm on a platform where `$ unset MYVAR` commands work

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Just

```
del os.environ['MYVAR']
```

should work.

Comment: The question was about removing items from the mapping, after all. If unsetenv is unsupported, then the key and value are removed from the mapping but remain set in the environment, neh?

Comment: If the key doesn't exist I think you get a KeyError.

Comment: for the record `del os.environ` worked for when `os.unsetenv` did not on OSX.

Comment: The docs on `del`: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement

Comment: FYI this solution is not idempotent. i.e. if `MYVAR` doesn't exist in the environment, you will get an exception. You can wrap it in a `try:` but it's unfortunate.

Comment: Security information: If someone wants to delete an environment variable for security reasons, this is not possible at least on Linux. For example it's common to pass secrets and passwords by env from docker into applications. If the process then unsets the variable, including Python methods below, the initial environment is still "frozen" available in `/proc/self/environ`. Any code running in the same process may simply read that file.

Answer (score 51):

For those who search for an elegant way to unset environment variable without errors if the variable does not exist:

```
os.environ.pop('MYVAR', None)
```

That works exactly as:

```
if 'MYVAR' in os.environ:
    del os.environ['MYVAR']
```

But if you need to deal with the exception, do what other users suggested: `del os.environ['MYVAR']` or `os.environ.pop('MYVAR')`.

Answer (score 12):

You can still delete items from the *mapping*, but it will not really delete the variable from the environment if `unsetenv()` is not available.

```
del os.environ['MYVAR']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need a valid method, such as in `TestCase.addCleanup()`

```
os.environ.pop('MYVAR')
```