# How to clear os.environ value for only one variable in Python

Tags: python, environment-variables

I'm setting `os.environ['PYTHONHOME']="/home/user/OpenPrint/py2.6"` in my Python script

But at the end of the script I need to clear this variable so that I can call another python script from a different location. Can someone tell me how to do that? I tried `os.environ.clear()` but that clears all the other variables too.

Comment: What you mean by clear? Does del os.environ[...] work? If not, just set it to ''

Comment: Are you calling the second script from this script or outside the script? Because if it's outside the script you don't have to clear the variable. When you set `os.environ[something]` that changes the environment just inside that particular python process, it's not permanent.

Comment: very similar question with 35+ upvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575165/what-is-the-correct-way-to-unset-a-linux-environment-variable-in-python

Answer (score 32):

Use

```
os.environ.pop("PYTHONHOME")
```

See (minimal) documentation at http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Answer (score 26):

try

```
del os.environ["PYTHONHOME"]
```

this delete variable "PYTHONHOME" from os.environ dict.

Answer (score 7):

To unset the environment variable **only** for the script being invoked, following will work too.

```
os.unsetenv('PYTHONHOME')
```

---

### UPDATE:

If you have to delete the environment for rest of the flow `os.environ.pop('PYTHONHOME')` or `del os.environ['PYTHONHOME']` is better. However, if you want to unset the environment variable only for the script you are forking at the end `os.unsetenv('PYTHONHOME')` works better as it still keeps the environment variable in current process environment. However it will also depend on how you are invoking the script.

Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.unsetenv) says

> Unset (delete) the environment variable named key. Such changes to the
>   environment affect subprocesses started with `os.system()`, `popen()` or
>   `fork()` and `execv()`.

See the example below.

**Sample script (/tmp/env.py)**

```
import os
print os.environ["VIFI"]
```

Now let's look at following.

```
vifi-a01:~ vifi$ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Oct 16 2019, 00:34:56)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> 'VIFI' in os.environ   # EnvVar not present initially.
False
>>> os.environ['VIFI'] = 'V' # set the env var
>>> os.system('python /tmp/env.py')  # child process/script gets it
V
0
>>> os.unsetenv('VIFI')   # unset env only for child script
>>> os.system('python /tmp/env.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/env.py", line 2, in <module>
    print os.environ["VIFI"]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'VIFI'
256
>>> 'VIFI' in os.environ    # rest of the flow still has it 
True
>>> os.environ['VIFI'] = 'V'  # set it again for child process/script
>>> os.system('python /tmp/env.py') 
V
0
>>>
>>> os.environ["VIFI"] = "V"  
>>> ^D
vifi-a01:~ vifi$ echo $VIFI

vifi-a01:~ vifi$ printenv | grep "VIFI"
vifi-a01:~ vifi$
```

Btw, setting the environment by `os.environ` is only local to the process (and it's child processes) in which it is set. It has no effect on global environment variables as you can see at the end.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html):

"calls to `unsetenv()` don’t update `os.environ`, so it is actually preferable to delete items of `os.environ`."

So I would suggest either of the other solutions over this one.

Answer (score 1):

For unit tests you can use `patch.dict` to clear all environment vars

```
class FooTests(TestCase):
    @mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {}, clear=True)
    def test_something(self):
```

(Ref: https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/10/13/how-to-mock-environment-variables-with-pythons-unittest/)